# Para que serve o underscore (ou underline _ ) na estrutura de repetição?

Tags: python, lista, variáveis, for

- O que este `_` faz?
- Qual motivo do mesmo estar sendo utilizado no trecho de código a seguir?

```
 print('3 numeros')
 data = []
 for _ in range(3):
     data.append(input())

 numbers = list(map(int, data))
 print(numbers)
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 11):

O `_` sugere **por convenção** que quer descartar o valor que normalmente seria guardado em uma variável. Neste caso está pegando uma faixa contando até 3, mas não deseja usar esse valor para nada, esta construção é feita apenas para controlar a repetição 3 vezes. Não é idiomático, mas seria basicamente o mesmo que escrever:

```
print('3 numeros')
data = []
i = 0
while i < 3:
    data.append(input())
    i += 1
numbers = list(map(int, data))
print(numbers)
```

Poderia ter escrito assim:

```
print('3 numeros')
data = []
for i in range(3):
    data.append(input())

numbers = list(map(int, data))
print(numbers)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/UnderlineConventionAlternative.py).

Dá na mesma, porém dá a impressão que essa variável será usada para alguma coisa, a convenção é que `_` não seria usada, ainda que tecnicamente isto seja um nome de  variável válido, então é só convenção mesmo, não é um operador ou algo especial na linguagem.

Comment: Eu daria destaque para a última frase: **é apenas uma convenção**.

Comment: Em python `_` é uma variável e não um operador? Por exemplo em `x, _, y = (1, 2, 3)` ou `x, *_, y = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` não seria o `_` um operador, nesse contexto, específico para o descarte?

Comment: @AugustoVasques vou destacar o trecho citado pelo Anderson, mas é isto que está na resposta, não? Quer que deixe isso claro também?

Comment: Na verdade eu desconhecia o conceito em questão, de que o `_` é apenas uma variável, e apenas pedi um esclarecimento de alguém que domina o assunto. Talvez meu erro tenha sido o fato de me interessar demais sobre o tópico e querer saber mais e ter apresentado outro contexto, que não era o foco da pergunta, buscando saber se o mesmo conceito se estende a outros casos de uso do `_`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques É o mesmo caso. O `_` será uma variável com o valor 2; você pode utilizá-lo normalmente (https://ideone.com/eHGB6x). A questão é que, dada a convenção, assim você informa ao leitor que o segundo valor não lhe será útil nas próximas linhas e que ele não precisará se preocupar com isso.

Answer (score -1):

O prefixo de sublinhado serve como uma dica para outro programador que a variável ou método começando com um único sublinhado é destinado para uso interno.  Essa convenção é definida no PEP 8. Isso não é imposto pelo Python. O Python não tem  distinções entre variáveis ​​"privadas" e "públicas", como o no Java

Comment: A linguagem é python. E operador `_` aparece em cinco contextos dentro da linguagem: Armazenar o último resultado interpretado, ignorar valores específicos, significados especiais, funções de internacionalização e separação de dígitos. O usuário foi específico na pergunta sobre qual o contexto de uso do operador e essa resposta não se aplica.

Answer (score -2):

O underscore (_) em python, usada numa estrutura de repetição, indica que estarias ignorando esse mesmo valor, em que na qual estarias guardando numa variável. Ou seja, o loop percorrerá, mas o valor passado ao  underscore será ignorado.